# Counting subsets in a set

Tags: combinatorics

Twelve philosophers sit around a table. In front of everyone of them there is a plate, between every two plates there is a fork and in the middle of the table there's a big bowl of spaghetti. Their time passes by in the following manner: they think, become hungry and reach for the spaghetti. But everyone of them needs two forks to eat. It's obvious that two philosophers, who are side by side, cannot eat at the same time. There is also a maximum number of people, who can eat at the same time - 6. What is the count of all 5-philosopher subsets, whose members can eat at the same time?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I struggle to find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

With 6 philosophers eating, there are six gaps, each of size 1.  With 5 philosophers eating, there are 5 gaps, of total size 7.  Hence there can be four gaps of size 1 and one gap of size 3, or three gaps of size 1 and two gaps of size 2.  This should get you started.